# Can I send data over my Arduino ethernet without "blocking" my sketch?

Tags: arduino, ethernet

Sorry for my bad english first.

I'm currently working on an Arduino project which is really simple.

I'm working on an attendance logger for my school to know how much time students are spending studying.
The RFID Reader part is working fine. When a tag is detected, I'm storing the value and the time in a SD Card. 
Every hour, my system have to send the logs to a web server to store it in a database and here come my problem. I'm struggling with the ethernet part.

Indeed, when I'm performing a HTTP Request, my sketch is "blocked" and students can't use the system anymore.
It's a real big problem, because if there are like 200 lines in my logs, sending those throught a request, one by one, will take really long.

I'm already aware of using millis() to use "multi-tasking".

I have absolutly no idea about how to send requests without "blocking" my sketch.. I'm not looking for someone to write my sketch. I just want to know if there is a way to avoid the "blocking" effect of the ethernet shield when I'm performing a request.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I don't know how you've set it up but I think the cheapest, simplest solution would be to get a second arduino clone for two dollars online. One could read RFID tags and write the data while the other transmits.

Comment: So correct me if I'm wrong but the idea would be to wire my ethernet shield to one arduino and my rfid reader to a second one. But how is the second one supposed to send data to the SD card of the ethernet shield ?

Comment: Yeah, true. I somehow imagined that they could both have access to the same storage media but if it's an SD card on a shield, it might require some hacking/soldering. Would it be possible to check for "incoming" readings in the transmission loop instead and break out of it in case someone's using the reader or is that the "send one line at a time"-solution that you want to avoid?

Comment: What about sending the lines one by one? When you have to send the lines, just send one, then loop, then send the second, loop again, and so on until you finish the log... And, how long does it take for it to send the whole log?

Answer (score 0):

Even if you send one by one, you dont have control over the server side. you have no gurantee that the server will **Always** response within a certain timeframe.
if your system is very busy, then this may not be your perfect solution.

on other hand, just a thought though, (*I dont have personal experience with ethernet shield*.)

you could send data serially from first arduino to second ardiuno, individually, every time RFID is detected. This should not take much time compare to the time to send 100 lines of logs. Now, one by one,  second ardiuno can save these data in its memory until it is finally sent to server.

now when second arduino is busy sending data to server, we can collect some those RFID reading in first arduino's memory, and pass to, when the things with server is done.

to check if second arduino is bg, we could set a pin high in second arduino until the server part is done.

but still, I dont see why do you have to send it every one hour. I am asuming you have your reason.

If you still want to save some time, the make a parallel data transfer between two arduino, instead of serially.

Comment: Well, your solution could be good. I will give it a try. And I need to send the data every hour because students don't have the same schedule. (I'm starting at 9 a.m for example, but one of my friend starts at 10 a.m). Since the system is here to gives information about students attendance, my database needs to be updated as much as possible.